# How do I access an ArrayList from a previous method in the same class?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

In this project, I'm trying to access information from an ArrayList which contains only the dates which are Strings.

Here is part of the class I tried.  If not having the whole class makes it hard to understand I can edit...

```
public ArrayList<String> getTicketDates(){
           ArrayList<String> theDateArray= new ArrayList<>();
           int i;

           for (i=0; i <tickets.size(); i++){
               if(tickets .get(i).getPurchased()== false){
                 theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate());
               }
             }
             for(int f=0; f<theDateArray.size();f++){
               System.out.println(theDateArray.get(f)+ " ");
             }
             return theDateArray;
           }       



     public int getTickets(String date){
         int tix= theDateArray.indexOf(date);
         int occurrences= Collections.frequency(theDateArray, tix);
         if (tix>=0){
             System.out.println(occurrences);


         }
         return occurrences;
     }
```

The 2nd class, I'm trying to count the amount of times one particular date occurs in the previous ArrayList, but it says that theDateArray cannot be resolved to a variable.

One method I've tried is just calling the entire method getTicketDates(), but what it does is it prints out the ArrayList triple, and the occurrences still don't work.

Comment: You should read about variable scope in java. Your arraylist is currently a local variable and therefor only available in local scope.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a newb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `theDateArray` variable scope is local to the `getTicketDates()` method, so you are not able to access it in the other method, so declare it as an instance variable as shown below:

```
public class YourTicketsClass {

    //declare ArrayList as an instance variable
    ArrayList<String> theDateArray= new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<String> getTicketDates(){
        int i;
        for (i=0; i <tickets.size(); i++){
            if(tickets .get(i).getPurchased()== false){
                 theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate());
            }
        }
        for(int f=0; f<theDateArray.size();f++){
           System.out.println(theDateArray.get(f)+ " ");
        }
        return theDateArray;
    }       

    public int getTickets(String date){
         int tix= theDateArray.indexOf(date);
         int occurrences= Collections.frequency(theDateArray, tix);
         if (tix>=0){
             System.out.println(occurrences);
         }
        return occurrences;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the array list outside of the method, then populate the list inside the method. Like this:

```
public class YourdataClass {
private List<String> theDateArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> getTicketDates(){
       int i;

       for (i=0; i <tickets.size(); i++){
           if(tickets .get(i).getPurchased()== false){
             theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate());
           }
         }
         for(int f=0; f<theDateArray.size();f++){
           System.out.println(theDateArray.get(f)+ " ");
         }
         return theDateArray;
       }       



 public int getTickets(String date){
     int tix= theDateArray.indexOf(date);
     int occurrences= Collections.frequency(theDateArray, tix);
     if (tix>=0){
         System.out.println(occurrences);


     }
     return occurrences;
 }
}/* end class */
```

Here are some references. http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/scope-and-lifetime-of-variables
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Scope

Comment: How is this different from my answer posted 9 mins ago?